# Historical weather data in France (Sceaux)

Tags: weather, france

I am looking for historical weather data (mostly temperature and sunshine hours) for France (specifically the City of Sceaux).

I found meteofrance who offer free  [historical weather data](https://donneespubliques.meteofrance.fr/?fond=produit&id_produit=90&id_rubrique=32) per day. The only way that I found to download the data is one file per day with all stations. What I would be looking for is a download of a single file that contains information for multiple days at the same station. So to say historical data per station, not per day. Does meteofrance or a similar source offer something like this or should I use weatherunderground for this?

Comment: Is Villacoublay too far away for your purposes? Can you use METAR reports (which include temperature, but not sunshine hours) for the station LFPV (Villacoublay). ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/ has large amounts of data (only one year at a time, but that's not bad)

Comment: The location looks promising. As far as I can tell the data that you linked to contains `ish`, not `METAR` formatted data or am I not seeing/understanding something?

Comment: Of course I can just as well use `ish` formated data. Just wondering.

Answer (score 2):

The wunderground API is pretty great for that. You just need to register for a key. Here is an ipython notebook to get you started: https://github.com/joshmalina/pollution/blob/master/notebooks/Build_historical_weather_data.ipynb

Comment: Is registering costly?

Comment: @sheß no, there is a free tier that allows you to make up to 500 api calls per day

Comment: that link https://github.com/joshmalina/pollution/blob/master/Build_historical_weather_data.ipynb is broken @compguy24

Comment: @brianray https://github.com/joshmalina/pollution/blob/master/notebooks/Build_historical_weather_data.ipynb

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery has NOAA data, this from the closest station I found to Sceaux:

```
SELECT year, mo, da, temp
FROM [bigquery-public-data:noaa_gsod.gsod2010] a 
JOIN (
  SELECT name, usaf, wban
  FROM [bigquery-public-data:noaa_gsod.stations] 
  WHERE country='FR' 
  AND lat BETWEEN 48.7 AND 48.8
  AND lon BETWEEN 2.2 AND 2.3
  LIMIT 100 
) b 
ON a.stn=b.usaf AND a.wban=b.wban
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

BigQuery also has ghcn_d data, but no station is as close as the NOAA one.

If you haven't tried BigQuery:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/bigquery/comments/3dg9le/analyzing_50_billion_wikipedia_pageviews_in_5/